# Keep tree menu open on page load

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the below Jquery script (which I don't really understand as never used it before)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
    $(".Treeviewcollapsible").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("Treeviewcollapse Treeviewexpand");
        $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

The script controls the epxantion and collapse of a tree menu in ASP.net mvc 5

The script is stored in ~/Scripts/Treeview.js and called from the ASP.NET mvc _Layout page

However when i click a link on the tree menu to open a new content page it collapses the tree menu.  Is there a way to keep the tree menu open throughout pages clicks?

It's all based on this:

http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/how-to-create-treeview-with-database-data-mvc4-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible solutions to this.

The problem is that Javascript does not remember its state (variables, DOM configurations etc.) between page loads. There are different ways to have Javascript data persist between pageloads, but since you seem to not be entirely comfortable with the jQuery script, you might want to solve this mainly from the server side.

I'm no expert on ASP.net mvc 5, but as long as you can get information about the active page where you set up your navigation menu, you can use this information to add the class "Treeviewexpand" to the menu point that needs to be expanded.

Then change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".treeview li>ul").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('Treeviewexpand')){
            $(this).css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
        }
    });
    $(".Treeviewcollapsible").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("Treeviewcollapse Treeviewexpand");
        $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

See a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/1xjr1ndf/

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me.  Also the example you posted, when I click a link the collapses on there too...

Answer (score 0):

You can store the state of the tree menu in something like HTML5's local storage.

So you could do

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var treeState = localStorage.getItem('treeState');
  var treeClass = treeState ? treeState : 'Treeviewcollapse';

  $(".Treeviewcollapsible").addClass(treeClass);

    $(".treeview li>ul").css('display', 'none'); // Hide all 2-level ul
    $(".Treeviewcollapsible").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        
        $(this).closest('li').children('ul').slideToggle();

        if ($(this).hasClass('Treeviewcollapse')) {
          $(this).removeClass('Treeviewcollapse').addClass('Treeviewexpand');
          localStorage.setItem('treeState', 'Treeviewexpand');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('Treeviewexpand').addClass('Treeviewcollapse');
          localStorage.setItem('treeState', 'Treeviewcollapse');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you are intending to do with the slidetoggle, so I left that alone. Move it/change it where needed to do what you want

Edit: Just realized that you may have more than one thing in the tree to be expanded. You can still do this but instead of storing the class, you would store the tree's selector and whether or not it is expanded.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me. I'll update my post with more information as perhaps it is more than just the JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Generic treeview expand to selected radio button. jquery 3.4, 3.6, etc. Change selectors as needed being mindful of case, like "UL" or add ".treeview" class as needed.

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(
    function(){
        if(this.checked)
            $(this).parents("UL").each(
                function(){
                    this.style["display"] = "block";
                }
            )
    }
);
```